# Air for iOS using StageVideo and executeInBackground simultaneously

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

Ok so I am not sure if there is any possible solution but I was hoping someone could offer some insight. I am building an app that requires a background process to run while the application is in the background. However, I also need to display hardware accelerated video using the StageVideo object.

The problem I have run into is that it seems that StageVideo requires the use of render mode: "direct" and background processes requires the use of render mode: "cpu".

Is there any known work around? Haven't had much look looking around google. Is it possible to change the render mode at runtime?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Air 3.9 beta promises to bring background execution to apps in direct mode.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashruntimes/air/

From the site:

> Mobile Support for Background Execution in “Direct” Render Mode – AIR now supports background execution of code on iOS and Android when render mode is set to “direct”.  This will allow your applications to perform tasks such as audio playback even when invisible to the user. Due to power and CPU considerations, we recommend reviewing our release notes for additional details and guidance.